# What is the maximum value of $\mathrm {Var} (X)$?

Tags: probability-distributions, variance

> Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with p.d.f $f(x)$ given by 
>   $$f(x)=
>  \begin{cases}
>    \theta x + \frac {1} {2} \  , & \text  -1<x<1 \\
>    0 \ , & \text elsewhere \\
>   \end{cases}$$
>
> where $\theta$ is a constant. Then the value of $\theta$ for which $\mathrm {Var}(X)$ is maximum is
>
> $(a)$ $1.$
>
> $(b)$ $2.$
>
> $(c)$ $\frac {1} {4}.$
>
> $(d)$ $0.$

I have computed it and found that $\mathrm{E}(X) = \frac {2 \theta} {3}$ and $\mathrm {Var} (X) = \frac {1} {3} - \frac {4 {\theta}^2} {3}$ and hence the maximum value of $\mathrm {Var} (X)$ is $\frac {1} {3}$. Which does not meet my purpose.

Would anybody tell me the given options are correct or not?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @AlexR. you may check easily that for every possible value of $\theta$ your property holds.

Comment: I think here the function is not continuous.

Comment: Because $\theta$ cannot take $\frac {1} {2}$ and $-\frac {1} {2}$ simultaneously.

Comment: Is it not (d) $0$?

Comment: Why? Please explain.

Comment: The maximum of $\mathrm{var}(X)$ is $\frac{1}{3}$, occuring when $\theta = 0$.

Comment: Oh sorry I have computed maximum value of $\mathrm {Var } (X)$ instead of finding the value $\theta$ for which it has been occured. My apologies.

Comment: Now my question is if $X$ is a continuous random variable then is it not true that the p.d.f. of $X$ is also continuous?

Comment: It need not be. Consider the continuous random variable $X$ which follows the probability density function $f(x) = 3x^2$ for $x \in [0,1]$. This is discontinuous at $x=1$. (the PDF of any r.v. must sum to $1$ and also be non-negative). It doesn't matter that it's discontinuous.

Comment: @Twenty-sixcolours thaks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that
$$
\mathbb EX = \int_{-1}^1{x(\theta x+1/2)dx} = \frac{2\theta}{3}
$$
and
$$
\mathbb EX^2 = \int_{-1}^1{x^2(\theta x+1/2)dx} =  \frac{1}{3}.
$$
Subsequently,
$$
\mathrm{Var}[X] = \mathbb E[X^2] - (\mathbb EX)^2 = \frac{1}{3}-\frac{4\theta^2}{9} =: f(\theta).
$$
Taking derivatives of $f$ with respect to $\theta$ and equating it to zero, we get
$$
f'(\theta) = -\frac{8}{9}\theta  = 0 \Longrightarrow \theta^*=0.
$$
The maximum variance is then $f(\theta^*) = 1/3$.